# JUnit TestGroup - None of the test groups are enabled

Tags: java, junit

I have grouped my test methods in 2 Test Groups like so -

```
    @TestGroup("integration")
    public abstract static class AbstractIntegrationTest {
        @ClassRule
        public static TestGroupRule rule = new TestGroupRule();
    }

    @TestGroup("unit")
    public abstract static class AbstractUnitTest {
        @ClassRule
        public static TestGroupRule rule = new TestGroupRule();
    }
```

And have my test methods defined this way -

```
    public static class UnitTest extends AbstractUnitTest {

        @Test
        public void Test1() {...}

        @Test
        public void Test2() {...}
}

    public static class IntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

        @Test
        public void Test3() {...}

        @Test
        public void Test4() {...}
}
```

When I try to run one of my test methods (say Test1) from the Intellij IDE, I get an error saying -

`org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: None of the test groups [unit] are enabled. Enabled test groups: []`

How can I enable my test group and if I am running a specific test, do I need to still enable anything?Have I set this up completely wrong?

Thanks.